# Pandas DataFrame filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My question is about the pandas.DataFrame.filter command. It seems that pandas creates a copy of the data frame to write any changes. How am I able to write on the data frame itself?

In other words:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.filter(regex='col1').iloc[0]=10
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

Desired Output:

```
   col1  col2
0    10     3
1     2     4
```

Comment: Anyone could explain the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need extract columns names and then use `loc` or `iloc` functions:

```
cols = df.filter(regex='col1').columns 
df.loc[0, cols]=10
```

Or:

```
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_indexer(cols)] = 10

print (df)
   col1  col2
0    10     3
1     2     4
```

You cannnot use `filter` function, because subset returns a Series/DataFrame which may have its data as a view. That's why `SettingWithCopyWarning` is possible there (or raise if you set the option).